# Why to assign an instance of a derived class to a variable which Type is not the one of the instance, but its base class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I've got 5 years experience. But to be honest while I know and use this construct...

```
Baseclass bc = new DerivedClass();
```

I have no idea what it actually does, not really, not truly. Is it a derived class or a base class? And I know that if I call bc.Method() I will get the derived class method. But only if I use the new keyword or override or something. To be honest I start to get a bit fuzzy here, I think I need to go back to basics with this, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: 5 years experience of what?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Comment: You ask for the meaning of instantiating extended classes to base class right? why don't you post a simple class structure of what you mean?

Comment: First create a console app for the above scenario and step through the code blocks, maybe that helps in refreshing and remove the fuzz

Comment: have a look at Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide) -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152(v=vs.80).aspx It's very similar to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an instance of DerivedClass and assigning it to a variable of type BaseClass. This can be useful if you have something like a base class Animal with two derived classes Fish and Dog, but you do not know which one will be instantiated and this is not important in your context because you are going to invoke a method which is defined in the base class. For instance you could have something like this:

```
Animal a;
if (whatever you want)
    a = new Dog();
else
    a = new Fish();
a.Feed();
```

Be careful with the use of modifiers, because if you define Feed in Animal with virtual and redefine it in Fish with override, the Fish version will be executed (it is linked at execution time). If you dont't mark the base version as virtual and mark the Fish version as new, the Animal version is executed (it is linked at compile time).

Comment: Francesco, this is a great response, I can see it clearly now! Thankyou...And the penny has dropped with virtual and override too.

Answer (score 2):

It creates an instance of `DerivedClass` and [implicitly casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it to type `Baseclass`.

As I assume that this compiles it means that either `DerivedClass` inherits from `Baseclass`, e.g.:

```
class DerivedClass : Baseclass
{
}
```

Or there is an [implicit cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for casting between these types, e.g.

```
class DerivedClass
{
    public static implicit operator Baseclass(DerivedClass d)
    {
        // return a Baseclass here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Using the following*

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

If we create a new instance of `Employee`, but our variable declaration is in fact `Person`, all that will happen is an implicit cast to `Person`, meaning we won't have access to any of the methods or properties in `Employee`. I suppose this could be useful if the constructor of `Employee` affects the constructor of `Person`, but we don't care about anything in `Employee`, however I wouldn't recommend it. Instead I would recommend constructing a method that utilises clearer polymorphism. This is when a derived object is used as a parameter, when in fact the parameter type is that of one of its bases, for example.

```
public void DoSomething(Employee employee)
{
    // here we do something with an employee
    // ...

    string fullName = GetTheirFullName(employee);
}

public string GetTheirFullName(Person person)
{
    return (person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName).Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just create an instance of `DerivedClass` and assign it to bc which is of type BaseClass

Comment: Nitpicking: actually it assigns the created instance to bc, which is of type BaseClass.

Comment: `bc` is actually of type "handle to `BaseClass`"